# C: What happens (in detail) in x=~x if x is of type char?

Tags: c, type-conversion, operators

If we have the following code:

```
char x = -1;
x =~x;
```

On an x86 platform with MS VS compiler (which partly supports C99) - what happens in detail when it is running?

To my knowledge, the following happens (please correct me if I am wrong):

- x is assigned the value -1, which is represented by the bit pattern 0xff since a char is represented by one byte.
- The ~ operator promotes x to an int, that is, it internally works with the bit pattern 0xffffffff.
- The ~ operator's result is 0x00000000 (of type int).
- To perform the assignment, the integer promotions apply (principally). Since in our case the operand on the right hand side is an int, no conversion occurs. The operand on the left hand side is converted to int. The assignment's result is 0x00000000.
- As a side effect, the left hand side of the assignment is assigned the value 0x00000000. Since x is of type char, there is another implicit conversion, which converts 0x00000000 to 0x00.

There are so many things that actually happen - I find it somehow confusing. In particular: Is my understanding of the last implicit conversion (of int to char) correct? What would happen if the assignment's result could not be stored in a char?

Comment: *"MS VS compiler (which supports C99)"* - Since when?

Comment: Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx

Comment: There is no integer promotion in your fourth bullet point. An `int` value is being assigned to a `char` object. The `int` value is converted to `char`.  There is no conversion of the left-hand side in an assignment.

Comment: That is a list of features for **C++**, a sister language to C, but a **different** language. MSVC does not support any dialect of C beyond C90.

Comment: @StoryTeller I believe OP was referring to [this particular part](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx#BK_CRT).

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Yes, that's the part I was referring to.

Comment: Supporting the C99 runtime required by C++11 does not equate to supporting C99 itself much at all. How is that point important to your question anyway?

Comment: @StoryTeller: I don't know, but I wanted to be specific because maybe it matters and some of you guys know better. I do know that C++ is not C. So you are saying the behaviour is the same for C11 and other versions of the C standard?

Comment: The behavior hasn't changed between C99 to C11 to my knowledge. Or since C90 for that matter.

Comment: @M.M: But doesn't an assignment sometimes require conversions, so that the compiler performs those conversions anyway?

Comment: @maya the right hand side is converted to match the type of the left hand side. The left hand side is not converted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed `~x` is an `int` type.

The conversion back to `char` is well-defined if `char` is `unsigned`. It's also well-defined, of course, if the value is in the range supported by `char`.

If `char` is `signed`, then the conversion of `~x` to `char` is implementation-defined, with the possibility that an implementation defined signal is raised.

In your case, you have a platform with a 2's complement `int` and a 2's complement `char`, and so `~x` is observed as 0.

Note that MSVC doesn't fully support **any** C standard, and neither does it claim to.

Comment: There is only implementation-defined behaviour on that conversion if the value were out of range. For the example in the question the value is `0` which is in range and therefore well-defined.

Answer (score 4):

You are almost correct, but missing out that `char` has implementation-defined signedness. It can either be signed or unsigned, depending on compiler.

In either case, the bit pattern for a 8 bit 2's complement char is indeed 0xFF regardless of its signedness. But in case the `char` is signed, integer promotion will preserve the sign and you still have value `-1`, binary 0xFFFFFFFF on a 32 bit computer. But if `char` was unsigned, `-1` would have been converted to `255` upon assignment and integer promotion would have given `255` (`0x000000FF`). So you'd get a different result.

Regarding integer promotion of `~`, it only has one operator to the right and that one is promoted.

Finally you assign the result back to `char` and the outcome will again depend on signedness. You'll have an implicit "lvalue conversion" upon assignment from `int` to `char`. The result is implementation-defined - most likely you get the least significant byte of the `int`.

---

From this we can learn:

- Never use `char` for storing integer values or for arithmetic. Use it for storing characters only. Instead, use `uint8_t`.
- Never perform bitwise arithmetic on operands that are potentially signed, or was made signed silently through implicit promotion.
- The ~ operator is particularly dangerous unless the operand is `unsigned int` or a larger unsigned type.

Comment: It also has an implementation-defined complementing scheme if `signed` (note that C++14 onwards insists on 2's complement char if it's signed), but +1 all the same.

Comment: Thank you for hinting at the point that the signedness of char is implementation-dependent. That does make a difference.

Comment: The term "lvalue conversion" does not refer to the conversion from `int` to `char`. (It actually means converting lvalue to rvalue, i.e. retrieving stored value from an object)

Comment: @M.M "The type of an assignment expression is the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion." and then one has to go read a long explanation about that below 6.3.2.1 where the most relevant part is "an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated
object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called lvalue conversion."

Comment: @Lundin In your first quote there is not actually lvalue conversion happening, it just mentions it as part of specifying the type of the assignment expression. Your second quote defines the term, which is certainly not a conversion from int value to a char. It is conversion *from* an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

> To my knowledge, the following happens (please correct me if I am wrong):
>
> x is assigned the value -1, which is represented by the bit pattern 0xff since a char is represented by one byte.

`1` is an *integer constant* of type `int`.  `-` negates that to -1 and remains an `int`.  -1 is assigned to a `char x` .  If that `char` is *signed*, then `x` takes on the value of -1.  If that `char` is *unsigned*, `x` takes on the value of `CHAR_MAX` which is also `UCHAR_MAX`. "bit pattern 0xff" is not relevant here, yet.

> The ~ operator promotes x to an int, that is, it internally works with the bit pattern 0xffffffff.

`x` is promoted to either `int` (or `unsigned` on rare machines where `CHAR_MAX` == `UINT_MAX` - we will ignore that).  An `int` is at least 16 bits.   The value of -1, when encoded as the overwhelmingly common 2's complement, is an all 1 bits pattern. (Other encoding possible - we will ignore that too).  If `x` has the value of `UCHAR_MAX`, then `x` will have the bit pattern `00...00 1111 1111` - assuming 8-bit `char`.  Other widths possible - another thing we will ignore.

> The ~ operator's result is 0x00000000 (of type int).

Yes, (unless `CHAR_MAX == UINT_MAX`, in which case it is `unsigned` and value 11...11 0000 0000).

> To perform the assignment, the integer promotions apply (principally). Since in our case the operand on the right hand side is an int, no conversion occurs. The operand on the left hand side is converted to int. The assignment's result is 0x00000000.

No integer promotions here due to assignment.  Promotions already occurred due to `~`.  A type change will occur, assigning an `int` to a `char`.  That is not a promotion.  The result is of type `char`. As part of the narrowing, the value of 0 goes through no range issues and results in a value of 0 and type `char`.  The value of 11...11 0000 0000 would go through implementation defined behavior and likely result in a value 0 and certainly type  `char`.

Had code been `(x =~x) + 0`, that `char` `(x =~x)` would have been promoted to `int` before the addition.

> As a side effect, the left hand side of the assignment is assigned the value 0x00000000. Since x is of type char, there is another implicit conversion, which converts 0x00000000 to 0x00.

Addressed in previous.

> What would happen if the assignment's result could not be stored in a char?

It is implementation defined behavior which value is saved.  It  could include (rarely) raising an exception.

---

Bit masking and manipulation is best handled using unsigned types and math.

Comment: Very clear answer. That was helpful for me, too. Thanks.

Comment: It was interesting in that aside from the usual 1) `char` as signed or unsigned 2) `char` a 8-bit or more, the other esoteric issues of 3) `int` encoding, 4) implementation defined narrowing all come into play with such short code.