# Large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow] warning in bit mask

Tags: c, gcc, bit-manipulation, bitmask

While creating a bit mask to set a bit in 8-bit register, I encounter this warning, but I can't see what can be wrong here:

```
static const uint8_t sck_pin_n_mask = ~(1 << SCK_LCD_PIN);
```

SCK_LCD_PIN equals 7.

If I try to change the type to int8_t the warning changes to:
`Overflow in implicit constant conversion`

Am I missing something, and what should I do?

Comment: You can silence the warning with `& 0xFF`

Comment: Or cast the value with `(uint8_t)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer promotion with the operator <<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203015/integer-promotion-with-the-operator)

Comment: [What happens (in detail) in `x=~x` if x is of type char?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51130848/995714)